# Не работает mysql_query на Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

Разработал сайт на windows на denwer. Все отлично работало. По необходимости перенес сайт на ubuntu на virtualbox. После проделанной работы не работают функции mysql_query, mysql_fetch_row и т.д.
Писал команды:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mysql
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql
```

Пишет, что установлена последняя версия.
В файле /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini отсутствует строка

```
;extension = mysql.so
```

Вообще нет ни одного файла с расширением .so. Не только в файле, но и во всем каталоге /etc/

В чем может быть проблема ?

Comment: Расширение `mysql` не поддерживается в PHP7. Пора переходить на `mysqli` или `PDO`

Comment: в каталоге /etc вообще не должно быть .so файлов, кстати

Answer (score 1):

В Денвере стоит php 5.3, поэтому для совместимости лучше подобрать Ubuntu с этой же версией php:

```
Ubuntu precise (12.04LTS) - php 5.3
Ubuntu trusty (14.04LTS) - php 5.5
```